# Spring boot context keeps trying to connect to java rmi server and failing

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I'm new to Spring, first off.

I'm using a Spring service to monitor an email account and act when a new message is added.
My Spring header code is:

```
@Component
public class EmailMonitor implements ApplicationListener<ContextRefreshedEvent> {
    private static final Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(EmailMonitor.class);

    @Override
    public void onApplicationEvent(ContextRefreshedEvent event) {
       // monitor emails
...
}
```

Whenever I start it I get a number of pages of

```
"RMI TCP Connection(1)-192.168.1.18: name = \"[Ljava.rmi.server.ObjID;\", codebase = \"\", defaultLoader = jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$PlatformClassLoader@332228c4","logger_name":"sun.rmi.loader"...
...
{"@timestamp":"2021-05-10T17:01:22.212+01:00","@version":"1","message":"RMI TCP Connection(1)-192.168.1.18: name = \"javax.management.ObjectName\", codebase = \"\"","logger_name":"sun.rmi.loader","thread_name":"RMI TCP Connection(1)-192.168.1.18","level":"DEBUG","level_value":10000,"appname":"email-notifier"}
{"@timestamp":"2021-05-10T17:01:22.213+01:00","@version":"1","message":"connectionId=rmi://192.168.1.18  4, name=org.springframework.boot:type=Admin,name=SpringApplication, attribute=Ready","logger_name":"javax.management.remote.rmi","thread_name":"RMI TCP Connection(1)-192.168.1.18","level":"DEBUG","level_value":10000,"appname":"email-notifier"}
{"@timestamp":"2021-05-10T17:01:22.213+01:00","@version":"1","message":"RMI TCP Connection(1)-192.168.1.18: [192.168.1.18] exception: ","logger_name":"sun.rmi.server.call","thread_name":"RMI TCP Connection(1)-192.168.1.18","level":"DEBUG","level_value":10000,"stack_trace":"javax.management.InstanceNotFoundException: org.springframework.boot:type=Admin,name=SpringApplication\n\tat java.management/com.sun.jmx.interceptor.DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.getMBean(DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.java:1083)\n\tat java.management/com.sun.jmx.interceptor.DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.getAttribute(DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.java:637)\n\tat java.management/com.sun.jmx.mbeanserver.JmxMBeanServer.getAttribute(JmxMBeanServer.java:678)\n\tat java.management.rmi/javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnectionImpl.doOperation(RMIConnectionImpl.java:1443)\n\tat java.management.rmi/javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnectionImpl$PrivilegedOperation.run(RMIConnectionImpl.java:1307)\n\tat java.management.rmi/javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnectionImpl.doPrivilegedOperation(RMIConnectionImpl.java:1399)\n\tat java.management.rmi/javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnectionImpl.getAttribute(RMIConnectionImpl.java:637)\n\tat java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)\n\tat java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:78)\n\tat java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)\n\tat java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:567)\n\tat java.rmi/sun.rmi.server.UnicastServerRef.dispatch(UnicastServerRef.java:357)\n\tat java.rmi/sun.rmi.transport.Transport$1.run(Transport.java:200)\n\tat java.rmi/sun.rmi.transport.Transport$1.run(Transport.java:197)\n\tat java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(AccessController.java:691)\n\tat java.rmi/sun.rmi.transport.Transport.serviceCall(Transport.java:196)\n\tat java.rmi/sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport.handleMessages(TCPTransport.java:587)\n\tat java.rmi/sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler.run0(TCPTransport.java:828)\n\tat java.rmi/sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler.lambda$run$0(TCPTransport.java:705)\n\tat java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(AccessController.java:391)\n\tat java.rmi/sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler.run(TCPTransport.java:704)\n\tat java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1130)\n\tat java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:630)\n\tat java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:831)\n","appname":"email-notifier"}
{"@timestamp":"2021-05-10T17:01:22.214+01:00","@version":"1","message":"[javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnectionImpl@6d666aa: connectionId=rmi://192.168.1.18  4] closing.","logger_name":"javax.management.remote.rmi","thread_name":"RMI TCP Connection(1)-192.168.1.18","level":"DEBUG","level_value":10000,"appname":"email-notifier"}
{"@timestamp":"2021-05-10T17:01:22.214+01:00","@version":"1","message":"[javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnectionImpl@6d666aa: connectionId=rmi://192.168.1.18  4] closed.","logger_name":"javax.management.remote.rmi","thread_name":"RMI TCP Connection(1)-192.168.1.18","level":"DEBUG","level_value":10000,"appname":"email-notifier"}
```

And then the program ends, when it's supposed to wait and listen to the javax email account notifier.

Any ideas on this? I'm unsure what the role of the RMI server is in this context (and I'm struggling to find doc references that tie up Spring and RMI). My understanding is that Spring will start the services it requires, but apparently not in this case.

Comment: And it should wait because? If there is nothing keeping the process alive it will start and directly shutdown. So unless you are creating a thread in the `onApplicationEvent` nothing will happen.

Comment: Maybe you're right. However my understanding is that "as long as the listener object is registered in the Spring application context, it will receive events. When Spring routes an event, it uses the signature of our listener to determine if it matches an event or not." So doesn't Spring keep it alive to keep listening?

Comment: No it doesn't keep it alive. It is an internal Spring even listener, not a JMS, Kafka etc. listeners for which a process would be started for monitoring. That and there is only 1 `ContextRefreshedEvent` going to be fired.

Comment: Also instead of writing your own I would suggest Spring Integration which has mail support out-of-the-box to do all of this.

Comment: That would be more useful. @M.Deinum could you add that (and the reference) as an answer and I'll accept it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To check for email and operate on it you are probably better of using Spring Integration which has out-of-the-box [email support](https://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/docs/current/reference/html/mail.html).

Regarding your question I suspect you misunderstood the [`ApplicationListener`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/context/ApplicationListener.html). It can be used to receive events fired through the internal event API of Spring. It won't start a listener thread like the listeners for Kafka or JMS would do. Althouhg both listeners in their own sense they are quite different beast.

But as mentioned you are probably better of using the [email support](https://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/docs/current/reference/html/mail.html) of Spring Integration, saves you from writing your own.

Answer (score 0):

I think you misunderstood the concept of spring context listeners.

Spring application context starts during the startup of spring driven application.
It has various "hooks" - points that you could listen to and be notified once they happen. So yes, context can be refreshed and when it happens, the listener "fires" and your code is executed. But that's it - it won't actually do anything useful afterwards, when the context starts. You can read about the context events [here](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-context-events) for example.

So with this in mind, basically your application context gets refreshed once, and the listener will be called also only once during the application startup.

Now I didn't understand how is RMI server related to all this :) You can remove the `@Component` annotation from the listener and restart the application, probably it will still search for the RMI server (please try that and update in the comment or something)

So first off, I think you should try to understand how is RMI related to all this, I think there is some other component in the system that gets loaded by spring boot and it searches for the RMI. Maybe You can take a thread dump or something and see which thread really works with RMI.

To get an event "when the message is added" is an entirely different thing, you will probably have to implement it by yourself or if the thirdparty that works with email has such a functionality - try to find how to achieve that with that thirdpary API, but for sure its not a ContextRefreshed event.